# Validation: Check if two numbers match and ignore symbols(like $,/. ) using jquery

Tags: jquery

I've got two input that I need to validate are matching in order to submit a form. The issue I'm having is that one input adds "$" and "," to the dollar amount and the other does not. They both do have two decimals at the end. So something like this example is matching but coming back as not matching.

#input1 = 1000.55
#input2 = $1,000.55

How can I match for just the numbers?

I tried having the $ sign , symbol added to the first input on blur, but that is causing more bugs when the input is edited more than once.

```
     $('#input1').blur(function () {
    const num = $("#input1").val().replace(/^\s*(?!\$)/, "")
    let amount = ("$" + format(parseInt(num)))    
    $("#input1").val(amount)  
 });         
}});
```

Comment: What are you using to compare them?  You could remove everything that isn't a digit, eg:  `"$1,001.55".replace(/[^\d\.]/g, "")`

Comment: I'm using a plugin that compares the two inputs and if they don't match a message is displayed on the browser. It looks like this. FormValidator.addValidation("input1",{eqelmnt:"input2",message:"Total amount must be equal to Total Requested Amount"} );

Comment: so, would I do something like this? if ($('#input1).replace(/[^\d\.]/g, "").val() != $('#input2').replace(/[^\d\.]/g, "").val()) {
                    return ({ elementobj: formobj.elements["input2"], message: 'Total amount must be equal to Total Requested Amount' });
                }